# How to change a windows handle class name or at least alias it to windows

Tags: c++, windows, qt, handle

I am working with an application that is attempting to grab my application via the window handle by class name. Unfortunately I can't change that application at all and have to make mine work with it. When my app launches the class name is "Qt5QWindowOwnDCIcon" now that it has been upgraded to Qt 5.7.1 but the old application is grabbing the window using the class name "Qt5WindowIcon". My application is written in C++.

My question is thus: Is there anyway to change my applications class name at the window handle level to be the old Qt5WindowIcon name WITHOUT removing OpenGL support or anything along those lines?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest to start with [GetClassInfoEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getclassinfoexa) for your main window.

Then you can [RegisterClass](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-registerclassa) for that [WNDCLASS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-wndclassa) with the `LPCSTR lpszClassName;` set to `"Qt5WindowIcon"`.

And then you subclass your main window using thie new window class.

Disclaimer: if your `Qt 5.7.1` defines window class `"Qt5WindowIcon"`, this may not work.

Comment: How would I apply this to a QMLApplicationViewer application? I don't really have a "MainWindow" persay. I have a QApplication that is running a QML app.

Comment: @BrianNurnberger Sorry, I don't know QT. I used the term `main window` loosely, meaning your window with that `Qt5QWindowOwnDCIcon` class name.